# Firefox 57 Quantum wrong font appearance in input[date]

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

Since i didn't find anything in the search i'll try my luck here.

With the new Firefox Update i have a strange rendering bug in the input[date] field which i can't resolve. Instead of my used Open-Sans Google Font i get some kind of monospace type inside the input[date] field. I know there is a checkbox in the preferences, which lets me choose my own output of fonts, but it's checked and the global font is still overridden. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is more a question for https://superuser.com But the default user agent style is set to `font-family: -moz-fixed` for `input[type="date"]`& `input[type="time"]`. You can set this font in about:preferences under *Advanced... > Monospace* Or you can use an user-script / extension to override this default style in every pages.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug, see [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1420824)

Comment: Thought so Lars, thank you for pointing this out! I hope this bug will be fixed asap since customers can be kind of annoying when something is not to solve immediately. ;)